# Sum of the n nth roots of unity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

1) If $z=\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$

2) Then apparently: $z^0+z^1+z^2...z^{n-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}=\frac{0}{1-z}=0$

Could someone please explain why: $z^0+z^1+z^2...z^{n-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$?

Comment: It's the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: or $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$

Comment: Note that the $n$-th roots of unity are the roots of $X^n-1$. If you've learnt about polynomials, this tells you immediately that their sum is $0$ and their product is $(-1)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $z^0+z^1+z^2...z^{n-1}= p(z)$.

Then $z \ p(z)=z^1+z^2+z^3...z^{n}$.

Hence $p(z)-zp(z)=1-z^n$.

$p(z)(1-z)=1-z^n$.

$p(z)=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$

If $z=\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Then there is a formula (that is easy to prove) that states for any $i \in \mathbb{R}$, $z^i=\cos\frac{2i\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2i\pi}{n}$. Hence $z^n=\cos\frac{2n\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2n\pi}{n}=1$. Substitute that in the last expression of $p(z)$.

Comment: Don't you mean $z^n = \cos \frac{2n\pi}{n} + i\sin \frac{2n\pi}{n} = 1$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yup. Was a little in a hurry there

Answer (score 1):

Sum of geometric series is given by $$\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$ where $|r|\leq1$ so $a=z^0=1$ and $r$ is common ratio here its $z$ now we know z is nth root of unity so $z^n=1$ thus we get $1-z^n=1-1=0$ . also we have proved an important fact that sum of roots of unity is $0$.