# The Sum of the n nth Roots of Unity (concerns the definition of the principal root)

Tags: complex-numbers

I was trying to answer the following question from Adam's *Calculus* and have a problem with the hint it provides. I have read the similar threads and my question does not concern the procedure of solving the question, but the hint the book provides. The book takes $w_1=|z|^{1/n}(\cos\frac{\theta}{n}+{i}\sin\frac{\theta}{n})$ to be the principal root, which in this case will be, based on $\theta=0$, $w_1=1$.

> Show that the sum of the n nth roots of unity is zero. Hint: Show that these roots are all powers of the principal root.

First, I wrote the polar form of the roots: $$w_1=\cos0+i\sin0$$,$$w_2=\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$$, $$...$$, $$w_n=\cos\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}$$

I can easily show that the $w_3,w_4,...,w_n$ are all powers of $w_2$, but not the powers of the principal root, $w_1$.

I have read these two threads: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728720/sum-of-the-n-nth-roots-of-unity) and [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122110/sum-of-nth-roots-of-unity) and know the rest of the calculation. But I cannot understand the hint. How can, for example, $w_2={e}^{{i}\frac{2\pi}{n}}$ be a power of $w_1={e}^{{i}0}$?

Comment: $w_1 = 1$. It's not the principal root. $w_2$ is.

Comment: If you have read these two threads, everything should be fine.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. My question concerns the hint provided. In the text, the book takes $w_1$ the principal root and according to the formula, I get $w_1=1$ as the principal root.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122110/sum-of-nth-roots-of-unity?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @EthanBolker But why does the book take $w_1=|z|^{1/n}(\cos\frac{\theta}{n}+{i}\sin\frac{\theta}{n})$ the principal root? I get $\theta=0$. Is this right?

Comment: I doubt that's what the book says. I think the $\theta$ in the formula should be $2\pi$ for the principal root. In any case your question is answered here and in the duplicates.

Comment: @EthanBolker Robert I don't know if you have access to the book, here is the reference: A. Adams, Christopher Essex, Calculus, A Complete Course (2018, 9th Ed.), Appendix I, A9. The threads you are referring to explain the solution. My question here concerns the hint given in this specific question of the book.

Answer (score 1):

The principal root is usually taken as $\cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)$,so it's your $w_2$. Note that that way $w_1=w_2^0$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was confused by the book taking $w_1=|z|^{1/n}(\cos\frac{\theta}{n}+{i}\sin\frac{\theta}{n})$ the principal root.

Answer (score 0):

Use Vieta's formula: If $z^{n}+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+.....+a_{1}z+a_{0}=0$ then setting $a_{0}=-1$ and every other coefficient zero we obtain $z^{n}=1$ and
$\sum_{1}^{n}z_{i}=-a_{n-1}=0$ and we are done!